# Why it's not possible to save a PNG image from Preview when a mask is added?

Tags: macos, preview

While adding some annotations to a PNG image, using the [Preview App](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preview_(macOS)), I added a mask to highlight part of the image -- Shapes » Highlight. After doing that I couldn't save the image anymore. I got the following error message:

> The document "[FILE_NAME]" could not be saved.

[image: Error message: The document could not be saved]

No detail about what is wrong was given. I tried different file names and directories. Also tried to use "Export" instead of "Save". Nothing worked.

Looking at [Apple's support page](https://support.apple.com/guide/preview/annotate-an-image-prvw1501/mac) I couldn't find anything about a specific format or something special about that tool.

I'm wondering what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 4):

This is a bug with Preview.

```
Preview -[CIImage initWithCGImage:options:] failed because the CGImage is nil.
Preview Error: CGImageForSavingWithFlattenedEXIF:depth: failed
Preview finalize:2403: image destination must have at least one image
```

You can report bugs to Apple at https://bugreport.apple.com.

Comment: Bug submission is no longer supported there. ... and this feature is still broken.

Answer (score 2):

I am having exactly same issue on my end. 
[image: not able to save highlighted picture in preview app]

Highlight is a function I need to use everyday. 
Hope Apple fix this as soon as possible.

Current stupid workaround is

1. Use preview to set highlight area.
2. Use command+shift+4 to take screenshot on preview.

Comment: I didn't think of taking a new screenshot. It's more work but it works. Haha!

Comment: does someone have time to tell me how to highlight a paragraph?  I'm not even sure what highlight does.

Answer (score 1):

Export to PNG before making changes.
Open the PNG file and edit it.
Use Instant Alpha to delete background.
Finalize and save.
For other changes I suggest exporting it to JPEG or other

Answer (score 1):

Alternative solution to screenshot...

1. Cmd + Shift + S to duplicate
2. Cmd + S to save
3. Save as PDF
4. *edit*
5. Export as PNG

Not really sure it's a *better* solution, just another workaround.

---

Follow up to this... It appears that Preview in Mojave is working. I was on the previous version when I posted this answer. I'm still not on Catalina yet, but it's working for me in Mojave.

Comment: The "Save as PDF" step is necessary?

Comment: Yeah. For whatever reason, you had to make Preview treat it as a PDF in order for the save to PNG feature to work. Certainly not ideal. I wish Apple would have fixed it.